# Смена с button на checkbox

Tags: javascript, button, checkbox

Есть кнопки при нажатии на которые вкл или откл вибрация

```
<button id="vibro_on" class="btn_vibro">ON</button>
<button id="vibro_off" class="btn_vibro">OFF</button>
```

Нужно поменять с кнопок на переключатель

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

Вот js код

```
let doVibro = Boolean(localStorage.getItem('doVibro') === '0' ? 0 : 1) || false;

document.getElementById("vibro_on").addEventListener('click', () => {
  switchVibro(true)
});

document.getElementById("vibro_off").addEventListener('click', () => {
  switchVibro(false)
});

const list = document.getElementsByClassName('doVibro');

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      doVibro ? navigator.vibrate([50]) : navigator.vibrate([0]);
     })
}


function switchVibro(bool) {
  doVibro = Boolean(bool);
  localStorage.setItem('doVibro', bool ? '1' : '0')
}
```

Нужно сделать привязку на чекбокс вкл и откл вибрацию.

Comment: Поискать пробовали?

Comment: да.. что то вообще не могу разобраться(

Comment: Поищите по текущим запросам (в гугле): `input="checkbox" mdn html`, `как привязать checkbox к label?`, `событие change mdn js`. Если вы сами не разберётесь, а за вас кто-то это сделает, то вы ничего не поймёте. Хотите разбираться - учитесь.

Comment: все пересмотрел, не могу разобраться. если можно пожалуйста готовый код.

Comment: В чём именно у вас возникли проблемы? Читали ли вы документацию по приведённым темам? Смотрели ли вопросы на StackOverflow?

Comment: да мне не понятно как по id="vibro_on" и id="vibro_off"
привязать два id на чекбокс для переключения

<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="slider"></div>
</label>

правда я в js вообще 0 мне бы готовое решение.
просто я понимаю что это уже не начинающий уровень что я хочу, я пересмотрел все но не могу понять как привязать айдишники к чекбоксу.

Comment: Выдаёте чекбоксу айди, и для лабелов `vibro_on` и `vibro_off` выдать атрибут `for` в котором будет айди чекбокса (в `for` записывайте айди без `#`!) и отключайте нужный лабел атрибутом `disabled`. Если вы думаете что это что-то продвинутое, то это не так, это задачи как раз таки для начинающих. Начните свою обучение хотя бы с [документации](//developer.mozilla.org). Элементы можно получить через `document.querySelector` и другие ему подобные, а пропорции элемента можно узнать либо самому через DevTools либо через поиск MDN'a. Не понимаю почему вы не нашли ответ, вроде всё объяснено...

Comment: понял спасибо! буду разбираться гуглить учить.. правда для меня все это вообще не понятно что вы написали) оч сложно)

Comment: Не забывайте и ответы на Stackoverflow смотреть, там бывают полностью написанный ответы, главное правильно свою мысль формулировать в поиске. Вы вообще молодец, что такую активность проявляете)

Comment: спасибо! та хочу научится, но что то совсем туго пока идет. буду стараться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не получится самостоятельно, то ниже ответ.
Что бы получше разобраться с событиями элементов и ознакомиться с ними, почитайте [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

В вашем случае, все решается созданием слушателя на событие [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) вашего чекбокса.

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="vibroSwitch"> <!-- Назначаем ID -->
<div class="slider"></div>
</label>

let doVibro = Boolean(localStorage.getItem('doVibro') === '0' ? 0 : 1) || false;

document.getElementById('vibroSwitch').addEventListener('change', (e) => { // Создаем слушателя
  switchVibro(e.currentTarget.checked); // Вызываем функцию и передаем свойство chacked нашего элемента
})

const list = document.getElementsByClassName('doVibro');

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    doVibro ? navigator.vibrate([50]) : navigator.vibrate([0]);
  })
}

function switchVibro(bool) {
  doVibro = Boolean(bool);
  localStorage.setItem('doVibro', bool ? '1' : '0')
}
```